# Create Custom Tab into Magento 1.9 Admin Panel

Tags: magento-1.9, module, admin-panel, category-products

This Problem is related to **Backend side** (Magento 1.9 Admin panel) not for Frontend side:

**Part: 1)**
- I wanna Create **Custom tab** (suppose '**CategoriesInfo**') in magento 1.9 admin panel. (like parallel to other top side tabs like, Dashboard,Sales,Category,CMS and etc )
- This tab has one sub_tab, '**categoryIDs**'
- When you click on '**categoryIDs**' sub_tab, it'll show one page at admin panel where i can write my logic to fetch all available categories.

**Part: 2)**
- It will show all the **Catagories** and **sub_categories IDs** and **Categories name** **with Checkboxs.**
- Admin can **select any category** then click on save button then data should be **save into file/DB** (for now in file).

Please Share Your ideas, Your ideas and efforts are appreciable for me, **Thanks**.

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to create admin menu and grid for display category and sub category on admin side.

Click on below link for how to create admin tab under any menu of main menu and show grid.

[Click here](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/)  for admin grid and custom tab.

If you want to create main menu on admin panel then some changes on above module.

Change according to below link in your adminhtml.xml

[Click here](http://inchoo.net/magento/getting-started-with-building-admin-module-in-magento/) for main menu in admin panel.

This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

follow this link for dynamic menu. [Click here](https://inchoo.net/magento/insert-dynamical-menu-in-magentos-admin/)

or for easy way follow this one. [Click here](https://tonytemplates.com/blog/how-to-create-a-new-menu-item-in-the-magento-admin-panel/)